# Using Docker Nginx, PHP, MySQL on Mac

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I'm just starting to get my head around docker and want to use it for a project.

I have followed https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples and have NGINX running fine and can see the NGINX landing page.

Do I need to install php-fpm and mySQL within my container since my container is only NGINX at this stage?

How do I configure my project on a custom domain e.g. `project.dev`. Do I need to edit an entry in `/etc/hosts` for `127.0.0.1 project.dev` and then listen for that URL in an NGINX config?

Lastly do I need a `dockerfile`? I already have my container up and my understanding is a dockerfile is only for defining your container?

An example of a dockerfile for NGINX, PHP and mySQL would be helpful to look at as well.

Thanks

Comment: I already have PHP and MySQL install on my mac so can this be shared by the docker container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this guide just show using nginx container in docker. But I see the container don't have php installed. And you cannot install `php-fpm` inside this container.

So, if you want to use `nginx`, `php`, and `MySQL` using docker you should `pull`:

1. Container which run Nginx + PHP-FPM (I recommend this image https://hub.docker.com/r/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm/)
2. Container run MySQL (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

**Download images**

```
docker pull richarvey/nginx-php-fpm
docker pull mysql:5.6
```

**Run MySQL Instance. Name it mysql56, and expose using port 3360**

```
docker run -tid -p 3360:3306 --name mysql56 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -v /root/docker/mysql56/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql  -d mysql:5.6
```

**Run Nginx PHP+FPM instance.  Link it to MySQL Instance, and name it project-dev**

```
docker run -tid --name project-dev --link mysql56:mysql -v $(pwd):/var/www/html -p 8888:80 richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest
```

Run `docker ps -a` to see the running containers.

To make nginx can be accessed with address `project.dev`, just map it on `/etc/hosts`. Then access it on web browser `http://project.dev:8888`

**Note**:

- `-v /root/docker/mysql56/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` it mean I have `/root/docker/mysql56/data/mysql` on my mac, and map it to `/var/lib/mysql` in `mysql56` container. So all mysql data will be backup on my local data, and will not lose when I remove the container.
- `-v $(pwd):/var/www/html` mean your current directory will be mapped to
  container. So, whatever you write in this directory will be exist on
  `/var/www/html` container.
- I use port `8888` to avoid conflict with existing web server, you can
  change it as you want

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a go

Comment: Is /root/docker/mysql56/data/mysql your default mysql install? Do I need to install mysql on my machine? I currently have it install via MAMP but I assume it isn't a good idea to map that version of MySQL?

Comment: oh no, I just create it manually to make data persitent in my local. So when container destroy, data will be keep on my local. You can custom the path as you want.

And you don't need to install `mysql` on your local. I'm not sure, `nginx php+fpm` container able to connect with `mysql` on your local. So, just use docker `container` which run `mysql` like I create in guide above.

Comment: other than ensuring the data is persistent is this required? This is a project that will be worked on by a few different people so having to configure that for each developer is not ideal. Is it fine to just omit that option?

Comment: No, just not use `-v /root/docker/mysql56/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql` option

Comment: FYI, to make connection from your `PHP` script to `MySQL`, please use `mysql` as the hostname. Because we use `mysql` as the name when link `nginx php+fpm` container (`--link mysql56:mysql `)